# Customizing the algoritm of the private key of Bitcoin (js)

Tags: javascript, private-key

Is there a way to change the Bitcoin private key creation algorithm so that only private keys are created whose extracted addresses start with "1a"?

A guide on the feasibility of this idea and how to implement it with JavaScript